# How can I force Webpack in a Next.JS app to resolve to a specific dependency from an external directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

Given the following directory structure, is it possible to have ALL react imports resolve to `react-b`?

```
 |__node_modules
 |  |__react-a
 |
 |__app-a
 |  |__component-a
 |
 |__next-app
 |  |__react-b
 |  |__component-b
```

```js
// component-a
import { useEffect } from 'react' // I need this to resolve to next-app/node_modules/react

export function() {
  useEffect(() => {} , [])

  return <></>
}
```

```js
// component-b
import ComponentA from "../app-a/component-a"

export function() {
  return <ComponentA />
}
```

The issue I am having is that we are migrating to a Next.JS app (`next-app`) but we want to continue to import components from (`app-a`). `app-a` is stuck for now on react 17.x.x but Next.JS is using 18.x.x. So when `next-app` is built, I need all react imports to resolve to react 18.x.x. At the time of writing this post we are using the `experimental.externalDir` setting to allow for importing components from outside the root of the next.js app.

The crux of it is that when importing from `app-a` I still need `react` to resolve to `next-app/node_modules/react`.

Webpack aliases seem to be the recommended answer generally but they don't appear to apply correctly in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this specific problem by using the next config [transpilePackages](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#module-transpilation) list. Some dependencies that are dependent on react are causing the react version mismatch by importing react from the root `node_modules`. By including these packages in the `transpilePackages` list in the next config, it seems that next is pre-compiling these libs using the correct react version.

Example:

```js
// next.config.js

const nextConfig = {
  ...other_config,

  transpilePackages: ["react-focus-lock"],
}
```

Unfortunately I haven't fully appreciated why this imports the correct react dependency while using webpack resolve aliases does not.